# How to check a set of names exist or not and display image in table using react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

My requirement i have a json object list using that i am checking for a name in json and if the name exist i am displaying a image from local assets folder. my code is below

After .map im displaying data like below

```
 <td>
                      <div>
                        <img
                          src={
                            DynamicData.CompanyName.includes("Lenovo")
                              ? LenovoImage
                              : DynamicData.CompanyName.includes("Dell")
                              ? DellImage
                              : null
                          }
                          alt="img"
                          className="DataLogo"
                        />
                      </div>
                    </td>
```

So here how can i display if i have more than 2 options is this approach is good ? are there any other approach ?

Answer (score 2):

If there are many values to check, this looks more convenient.

```js
const imagesMapping = {
  Lenovo: LenoviImage,
  Dell: DellImage,
  // other values
}

const company = Object.keys(imagesMapping).find(name =>
  DynamicData.CompanyName.includes(name));

const image = company ? imagesMapping[company] : null; // instead of null better use a DefaultImage
const result = <img src={image} alt="img" className="DataLogo" />
```